# When do we use hibernate's session flush against setComplete()

Tags: hibernate, spring, flush

I've read spring documentation regarding Hibernate's setComplete() method while working with Unit Test Cases. I am confused between setComplete() versus session's flush() method. Both are responsible to make object's state persistent in Database by loading from memory to actual Database. It will be great if somebody can help me to get good resources/examples regarding the same. I will highly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Maulik

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, [`setComplete()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests.html#setComplete%28%29) is **not** part of Hibernate's API (please provide a link when you are referring to something), it is part of the API of  [`AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests.html) which is a *convenient base class for JUnit 3.8 based tests that should occur in a transaction, but **normally will roll the transaction back on the completion of each test**.* The [`setComplete()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests.html#setComplete%28%29) method allows to alter this default transactional behavior. From its Javadoc:

> **Cause the transaction to commit for this test method**, even if default is set to rollback.

The following section of the documentation gives more concrete use cases:

> #### [8.3.6.3. Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#junit38-legacy-tx)
>
> `AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests`
>   depends on a
>   `PlatformTransactionManager` bean
>   being defined in the application
>   context. The name doesn't matter due
>   to the use of autowire by type.
>
> Typically you will extend the
>   subclass,
>   `AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests`.
>   This class also requires that a
>   DataSource bean definition - again,
>   with any name - be present in the
>   application context. It creates a
>   `JdbcTemplate` instance variable, that
>   is useful for convenient querying, and
>   provides handy methods to delete the
>   contents of selected tables (remember
>   that the transaction will roll back by
>   default, so this is safe to do).
>
> If you want a transaction to commit
>   programmatically - unusual, but
>   **occasionally useful when you want a particular test to populate the
>   database** - you can call the
>   `setComplete()` method inherited from
>   `AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests`.
>   This will cause the transaction to
>   commit instead of roll back. As an
>   alternative, if you are developing
>   against Java 5 or greater and
>   extending
>   [`AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#junit38-legacy-annotation-aware-tests),
>   you may annotate your test method with
>   `@Rollback(false)` to achieve the same
>   effect through configuration.
>
> There is also the convenient ability
>   to end a transaction before the test
>   case ends, by calling the
>   `endTransaction()` method. This will
>   roll back the transaction by default
>   and commit it only if `setComplete()`
>   had previously been called. This
>   functionality is useful if you want to
>   test the behavior of 'disconnected'
>   data objects, such as Hibernate-mapped
>   entities that will be used in a web or
>   remoting tier outside a transaction.
>   Often, lazy loading errors are
>   discovered only through UI testing; if
>   you call `endTransaction()` you can
>   ensure correct operation of the UI
>   through your JUnit test suite.

Hibernate's  `Session#flush()` is very different, it just tells Hibernate to write pending changes to the database, it doesn't interact with the transaction.